# how to bind controls of two different wpf windows

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I dont know how to bind two controls from different wpf windows (for example: textbox from mainwindow and textblock from window1).
I`ve been looking for any example for ages, but my attempts are in vain. Please, send a link with an example of this or write code..
any help will be appretiated 
p.s. sorry, my english is bad.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to directly bind 2 controls from different windows but you could use the Datastore for this, open your project in Blend and follow these steps:

Step 1. Add a window to your project and name it whatever you want.

Step 2. Add a Textbox control to your mainwindow and to the new window you created.

Step 3. go to the "Data" window and pick "Create data source" \ "New Data Store".

Step 4. the new datastore you created is added to your project with 1 field now named Property1, by default blend adds a text string to that field "value" you'll need to clear that one out, click on the "Edit data store values" and clear anything in the value field.

Step 5. now all you need to do is to bind both textbox's text property to that datastore field, check this image:

https://postimg.org/image/8nz5xki13/